# No FileSystem for scheme: oss

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, alibaba-cloud

I am using Alibaba cloud to store processed data from the spark scripts but I am unable to upload the data to storage. I know it with s3 by including some jars but not sure how to do it in Alibaba OSS service

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession

conf = SparkConf()
conf.set("spark.hadoop.fs.oss.impl", "com.aliyun.fs.oss.nat.NativeOssFileSystem")
spark = SparkSession.builder.config("spark.jars", "/home/username/mysql-connector-java-5.1.38.jar") \
    .master("local").appName("PySpark_MySQL_test").getOrCreate()

wine_df = spark.read.format("jdbc").option("url", "jdbc:mysql://db.com:3306/service_db") \
    .option("driver", "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").option("query", "select * from transactions limit 1000") \
    .option("user", "***").option("password", "***").load()

outputPath = "oss://Bucket_name"
rdd = wine_df.rdd.map(list)
rdd.saveAsTextFile(outputPath)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think maybe it is due to you do not open the authority of OSS.
In your OSS ,click your bucket---authorize. changed to the related rules, like add conditions IPs.
it could work for you.